# docker machine stuck while creating

Tags: powershell, docker, docker-machine, hyper-v

I was creating a docker machine on my Windows 10 as per instructions from `Docker` page. After running the command it gets stuck in some place.

The output from the `PowerShell`:

> PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker-machine create --driver hyperv vm
>
> Running pre-create checks...
>
> Creating machine...
>
> (vm) Copying C:\Users\HP.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to
>   C:\Users\HP.docker\machine\machines\vm\boot2docker.is o...
>
> (vm) Creating SSH key...
>
> (vm) Creating VM...
>
> (vm) Using switch "DockerNAT"
>
> (vm) Creating VHD
>
> (vm) Starting VM...
>
> (vm) Waiting for host to start...
>
> Waiting for machine to be running, this may take a few minutes...
>
> Detecting operating system of created instance...
>
> Waiting for SSH to be available...
>
> Detecting the provisioner...
>
> Error creating machine: Error detecting OS: OS type not recognized

I waited for over one hour. It didn't proceed further. Please help, what's wrong?

Comment: you can update Windows to 1709 and use a more native way of running containers.

Comment: How do I do that? I created an external switch by referring on GitHub. Now its stuck in "waiting for host to start...".

Answer (score 2):

In a shell type "docker-machine ls".  You will see that the VM is running but the URL is blank. The problem is that the network address cannot be assigned.

Use Hyper-V Manager to stop the vms.  Then open virtual switch manager.  For the external network switch adapter to one that is actually part of a network.

Go back to Hyper-V Manager and start the VMs.  In a shell use "docker-machine ls" and you will find that the network addresses are now defined.

In my case the adapter was the Ethernet connection which was unplugged.  Once I switched to the wifi adapter everything started working.

Comment: if anybody is using the above solution then this link will help you out. https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/hyper-v/#example